# Validating "scp" in Api Management's validate-jwt

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-api-management

I am attempting to validate that a passed in JWT token has the scopes "labresults.read" and "user_impersonation". I did the following policy snippet

```
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Invalid JWT Token" require-signed-tokens="true">
    <openid-config url="(snip)" />
    <audiences>
        <audience>(snip)</audience>
    </audiences>
    <required-claims>
        <claim name="scp" match="all">
            <value>labresults.read</value>
            <value>user_impersonation</value>
        </claim>
    </required-claims>
</validate-jwt>
```

I pass in a token that looks like

```
{
  "iss": "(snip)",
  "exp": 1522334650,
  "nbf": 1522331050,
  "aud": "(snip)",
  "sub": "(snip)",
  "email": "(snip)",
  "name": "Scott Chamberlain",
  "scp": "labresults.read user_impersonation",
  "azp": "(snip)",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "iat": 1522331050
}
```

When I do a "Try It" from the developer portal looking at the tracing the on-error reports

```
validate-jwt (648 ms){
    "message": "JWT Validation Failed: Claim value mismatch: scp=labresults.read.."
}
```

Am I forced to use a single claim of

```
<claim name="scp">
    <value>labresults.read user_impersonation</value>
</claim>
```

I really would not like to as I do not want to force on the consumers of this api that those two scopes will be the only things passed in and in that specific order.

What do I need to do to validate the scope the propper way?

Comment: Here is a link to the [sister post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d0196d45-0a0a-49b9-98c9-862be18bf4a4/validate-scp-claims-in-validatejwt?forum=azureapimgmt) on the msdn fourms

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from someone at Microsoft on the MSDN Forums.

> I would suggest you to specify “separator” attribute in policy
>   statement to validate the JWT token and see if it helps. For more
>   information, you might refer this document:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT.
>
> Swikruti BoseMicrosoft-MSFT (MSFT CSG)

I totally overlooked the seperator attribute when i looked at the documentation the first time.